# How do I use the Clojure `use` function in leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am very new to both Clojure and Leiningen. I have installed Clojure on Windows at `C:\clojure-1.5.1` and leiningen-win-installer beta1 at `C:\.lein\bin`.

Now I am trying the example from Eric Rochester's book. I have included dependent libraries for Incanter in project.clj and also using dep.

How do I use the command `(use 'incanter.core)`? I am getting `'use' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. In addition, how do I use lein commands at `user=>`?

Comment: Did you start the REPL using `lein repl`?

Comment: Yes, I did.                                                   C:\.lein\bin>lein repl
nREPL server started on port 3977 on host 127.0.0.1
REPL-y 0.3.0
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e
user=> (use 'incanter.core)
FileNotFoundException Could not locate incanter/core__init.class or incanter/core.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
user=>

Answer (score 1):

Edit - I forgot "lein deps" until I saw Mars's answer

Before you start lein repl, you have to make the project (with "lein new getting-data" or whatever is in the book).

That makes a new directory, and in that directory you find and edit "project.clj" to include the dependencies (as shown in book).

cd into the directory that project.clj is in and run "lein deps" from the dos/powershell prompt.

THEN when you run lein repl, from within that same directory, at the user=> prompt, do

```
(use 'incanter.core)
```

and it will come back with "nil" and you'll be running.  You might want to first run some examples from the leiningen page to get more of a feel for lein.  You always type clojure commands at the "user=>" prompt, not at the "c:....>" prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of subtlety in Leiningen project.clj's.  I haven't found an easy introduction.  Levin Magruder's advice will no doubt get you started.  The basic idea is that once the project file is set up correctly, `lein deps` will go out and find the libraries you need, and put them in a place where `lein repl` can find them.  Then `use` will work for the libraries that have been downloaded.  For more info, study of the detailed comments [project.clj sample file](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj) may be helpful.  (Not part of the answer to this question, but if you're having problems with `use`, you're likely to get tripped up by `ns` and filenames soon (I was): I recommend [Colin Jones' introduction to `ns` and its options](http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.htm).)