# Using incanter in leiningen/ clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen, incanter

I am new to clojure, and coming from R, I would like to work with Incanter.

Basic question: How do I run it?

I am running Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_65 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM on a 64 Debian machine.

The following dependencies were installed in the project.clj file [from Eric Rochester's book: Clojure Data Analysis Cookbook].

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
    [incanter/incanter-core "1.4.1"]
    [incanter/incanter-io "1.4.1"]])
```

What the book does not say, but is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813742/how-do-i-use-the-clojure-use-function-in-leiningen), I cd'd to the folder holding the project.clj file and ran "lein deps". This imported a bunch of files [I see indeed incanter-core 1.4.1 and incanter-io 1.4.1].

When I now run "lein repl" from the same directory where the project.clj file is, I get:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate incanter_core__init.class or incanter_core.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

This has probably something to do with namespaces, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put [incanter "1.5.5"] in your dependencies vector (instead of what you've put) also [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] would be better

Sadly the Incanter website still doesn't state the latest version for Leiningen, it should be at the top of the page!